# Delphi Seattle "Camera on IOS give typecast error"

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I trying to use the camera in a small app but getting this error:

> Error: Invalid Class Typecast

What I did is:

- New multi device application
- Action list Component
- `TakePhotoFromCameraAction1` added to Actionlist
- one button  with action connected to `TakePhotoFromCameraAction1`

Run 64 bit IOS9 Ipad  Error

Run 32 bit  IOS9 Ipad  Error

It looks like the error is coming in this function `FMX.MediaLibrary.Actions()`.

```
procedure TTakePhotoFromCameraAction.ExecuteTarget(Target: TObject);
begin
  if IsSupportedInterface then // This line create the error
    FCameraService.TakePhoto(Target as TControl, GetParamsPhotoQuery);
end;
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I send it to Embacadero support as a case , and it is a bug.

Answear and hotfix below

---

The invalid typecast looks to stem from the fact that you are using a TSpeedButton. The TakePhotoFromLibraryAction will work if you use a TButton. The problem happens in TTakePhotoFromLibraryAction.ExecuteTarget where the Target is passed as a TObject. The debugger therefore doesn't give any clue as to what class the target is but it presumbably is not a descendent of TControl which is what it needs to be if the cast is to succeed.

I shall log a bug for this but in the meantime, I suggest that you use a TButton to call this action.

Answer (score 0):

- My TSpeedButton sits on on TListbox item.
- I encountered the Invalid Class Typecast error
- I changed TSpeedButton to TButton type. But the error still returns if you accidentally click on the list item and not the TButton.
- Eventually i switched my code from ActionList to this approach:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Taking_Pictures_Using_FireMonkey_Interfaces

- Worked for me, yet still using TSpeedbutton.

Comment: problem was when one would use the predefined action, but indeed could use your own action and talk to the camera using the Firemonkey interfaces (there is also a camera component one could use)